# Best approach to copy tables from AWS PostgreSQL to Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, data-migration

I am looking for a best approach to copy many tables from AWS PostgreSQL to Redshift db as below requirement:

-We need to copy around 90 tables from 7 AWS PostgreSQL databases to 1 Redshift db

-Full refresh every 30 minutes is required

-Most of tables are small, just some big tables (around 10-150M records)

I am thinking about Glue, but we might have better approach on AWS?

Hope I can have some help to make decision.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you going to do about `VACUUM`?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what AWS DMS (Data Migration Service) is designed to do.  I think you it will can meet your needs and cost less than Glue.  Glue can also get complex to use if your needs don't fall neatly into the basic patterns.

For this small size I personally would go even simpler than DMS.  A lambda function that extracts small table data and moves it to RS is simple and costs next to nothing.  A Step Function could invoke the Lambda with different small table names in a loop.  Your larger tables could be updated by (the same) Lambda with some time based limits on what to update and some info about table keys.  I'd go this route b/c writing this code is easy for me (done it before).  My best advice to go with the skillset you already know, have and understand.  Let the tool choice flow from that (if it meets requirements - like cost).

Comment: Much appriciate your help Bill. I'll have a look on DMS approach.